# java - json throws JsonParseException: Unexpected character while converting json to java object

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jackson

I have web-service created on Spring framework with Postgres database. I use JpaRepository to manipulate with my database and Rest controller. I try to save an object to my database using jquery but I get an error. 
What should I change in my jquery call and rest controller to execute successfully?

Here is jquery call

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/products',
    type: "POST",
    data: { "productName":"product", "amount": 123, "dateArrival": 1522345884907},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Function I use to an save object to the database in `RestController`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.POST
,consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Product saveProduct(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity){
    String json = httpEntity.getBody().trim().replaceAll("\uFFFD", "");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Product product = null;
    try {
        product = mapper.readValue(json,Product.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return service.save(product);
}
```

String after reading httpEntity

```
productName=product&amount=123&dateArrival=1522345884907&_token=undefined
```

Here is my entity

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "Stock")
public class Product {
    public Product() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")

    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Product_name", nullable = false, length = 25)
    @JsonProperty("productName")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "Amount", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "Arrival_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateArrival;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Date getDateArrival() {
        return dateArrival;
    }

    public void setDateArrival(Date dateArrival) {
        this.dateArrival = dateArrival;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", productName='" + productName + '\'' +
            ", amount=" + amount +
            ", dateArrival=" + dateArrival +
            '}';
    }
}
```

And the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('p' 
(code 112)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 
'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@9e3ef9; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: Could you please show us the concrete JSON that causes this error?

Comment: { "productName":"product", "amount": 123, "dateArrival": 1522345884907}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the string that you have just after reading from the HttpRequest body.

Also can you try to run it without the unicode character replacement i.e. remove the `replaceAll("\uFFFD", "")`

Comment: productName=product&amount=123&dateArrival=1522345884907&_token=undefined

Comment: That does not look like valid json. In your Ajax request change the `data: { "productName":"product", "amount": 123, "dateArrival": 1522345884907}` to `data: '{ "productName":"product", "amount": 123, "dateArrival": 1522345884907}'` OR `data: JSON.stringify({ "productName":"product", "amount": 123, "dateArrival": 1522345884907}`)

Comment: But now i  get %7B%22productName%22%3A%22product%22%2C%22amount%22%3A123%2C%22dateArrival%22%3A1522345884907%7D=&_token=undefined

Comment: Add dataType:json. Did you do JSON.stringify() or passed as String?

Answer (score 0):

Your input String:

```
productName=product&amount=123&dateArrival=1522345884907&_token=undefined
```

is not JSON. While exception is not very specific, it does indicate that very first character ('p') is unexpected; JSON would need to start with `{` character (with possible leading whitespace).